# C dl* how to swap a function pointer for another function pointer

Tags: c, algorithm, function, dynamic, wrapper

How do i safely swap a function for another function in C, as i have this

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void *(*malloc_mem_real)(size_t);
void *(*calloc_mem_real)(void*,size_t);
void *(*realloc_mem_real)(void*,size_t);
void (*free_mem_real)(void*);

void memory__init(void) {
    if (!malloc_mem_real) malloc_mem_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
    if (!calloc_mem_real) calloc_mem_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "calloc");
    if (!realloc_mem_real) realloc_mem_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "realloc");
    if (!free_mem_real) free_mem_real = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "free");
}

/*
const char *getObjectName (object *anObject) {
    static char * (*func)();

    if(!func)
        func =  dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getObjectName");
    printf("Overridden!\n");     
    return(func(anObject));    // call original function
}
*/

void* _malloc(size_t sz);

int bit, saved;

void swap_malloc() {
    if (bit == 0) {
        void *(* malloc)() = &_malloc;
        bit = 1;
        write(1, "1\n", 2);
    }
    else if (bit == 1) {
        void *(* malloc)() = &malloc_mem_real;
        bit = 0;
        write(1, "0\n", 2);
    }
}


void* _malloc(size_t sz) {
    swap_malloc(); // should swap void* _malloc(size_t sz) for void* malloc(size_t __size), bit = 0
    return malloc(sz*2); // returns libc malloc(sz*2);
}

void* malloc(size_t sz) {
    if (saved == 0) {
        memory__init(); // save real malloc address
        saved = 1;
    }
    swap_malloc(); // should swap void* malloc(size_t sz) for void* _malloc(size_t sz), bit = 1
    return malloc(sz); // returns _malloc(sz);
}

int main() {
    char * h;
    h = malloc(50); // should allocate 100 instead
    printf("%p\n", h);
    free(h);
    return 0;
}
```

which is meant to swap the files malloc for libc malloc but swap_malloc keeps being called recursively resulting in write: stack overflow

The basic idea is this:

calls malloc wrapper

swich malloc wrapper to libc malloc

Do functions that require libc malloc, for example printf

switch libc malloc back to malloc wrapper

Comment: You shouldn't need mallocs to swap pointers.

Comment: What a peculiar piece of code. Why do you wait to call your own `malloc` before calling `memory__init()`? Are you chasing a bee in the woods?

Comment: @RobertHarvey is it meant to automatically swapped when malloc is called, from my malloc to libc malloc, do the malloc, then swap back to my malloc, so it does not do malloc > malloc > malloc > malloc > malloc > malloc loop cus it is calling itself recursively, it is meant to do malloc > libc_malloc (swich back to malloc) so the next time malloc is called it switched to libc malloc then back to my malloc... with the reason being its use as a self resetting wrapper like how u wrap something then call dlsym(next) on it but u can no longer access the wrapper as it is now set to the next occurence